# Is there an R function to run a piece of code multiple times with 3 seconds interval

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I have a code snippet to get data from a MYSQL database table. I would like to continue refreshing the dataframe for every 3 seconds.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
library(tictoc)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='password', dbname='test_data', host='localhost')

dbListTables(mydb)

rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from rawdata")

data = fetch(rs)

View(data)
```

Is there an R function like "ReactiveFileReader" to work with a database engine ? Or would you please help with a code snippet to run this code multiple times for every 3 seconds. Thanks

Comment: Maybe add in some `sleep` within some loop?(Not sure if there's a SQL native "timer")

Comment: Hey @NelsonGon do you think you can help with a code snippet ?

Comment: Delay? SQL Server: `waitfor delay '00:00:03'; select 1 as a;`. Postgres: `select pg_sleep(3), 1 as a`; [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep): `select sleep(3);`.

Comment: But perhaps it's better to handle this in R, with something like `while (TRUE) { Sys.sleep(3); dat = dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from rawdata"); do_something_with(dat); }`. (I'm assuming `DBI` here, not the 8+ years old `dbConnect` that I just learned about today :-)

Comment: @r2evans bit confusing. Do you think your snippet can be integrated with my code ? Help needed plsss

Comment: If you want this to run automatically, that to me presumes no human interaction, so `View` is not meaningful. What are you hoping to do with the data once it is retrieved every few seconds? Another btw: this is a 3 second pause, not retrieved every 3 seconds. While the difference might be semantic, if you need strictly 3-second intervals then you'll need a bit more logic, and even then you are likely to fall prey to network lag.

Comment: Every 3 seconds: drop `dbListTables` and `View`, so the only thing left is connect (or re-use an existing connection) and pull the data. What do you want to do with the data? Save it to a file? Process and re-insert? Just have it dump to the console, hoping that a human somewhere is paying attention?

Comment: I'm trying to maintain a data-frame that is continuously kept refreshed. Yes automatically. This df will be connected to a shiny dashboard visuals on a tv monitor

Comment: @r2evans a working code snippet will make me happier.... please

Comment: Okay, you're missing a lot of context from this question. Keeping a `data.frame` updated is easy (code in my comment does that) but it updates a frame that nobody sees. Since you said `shiny` dashboard, do you think it's relevant to include that in your question? (*I do.*) Have you tried `shiny::reactiveTimer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll adapt the example from `shiny::reactiveTimer`. Tested on my database/instance (not `RMySQL`, but close enough).

```r
library(DBI)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("mytbl")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Anything that calls autoInvalidate will automatically invalidate
  # every 2 seconds.
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(3000)

  mydb = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user='root', password='password', dbname='test_data', host='localhost')

  mydat <- eventReactive(autoInvalidate(), {
    DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from rawdata")
  })

  output$mytbl <- renderTable(mydat())
}
```

Comment: The dataframe is in `mydat()`. Where do you expect it to be?

Comment: And this code works fine for me on my database and my table.

Comment: please if i need to get mydat into a dataframe that is visible under environment tab. How can i do that ? please

Comment: While scope-breach like that is typically discouraged, you can use [`assign`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) to assign variables to other environments (such as `.GlobalEnv`).

Comment: ok, I would appreciate a code snippet pls. This is bit confusing

Comment: Read the link I provided, or type in `?assign` (same thing), the examples are at the bottom of the help documentation.

Comment: If "served" by a shiny server, probably yes, since reactivity can be used.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to have a function to run every n times with delay, but the problem is that the data will be stored for every replication so it can become very big soon:

```
f <- function(){
    Sys.sleep(3)#delay time here
    mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='password', dbname='test_data', host='localhost')
    dbListTables(mydb)
    rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from rawdata")
    fetch(rs)
}

# use replicate to run the function n times with delay time
data <- replicate(10, f())
```

we will get data as a vector with all delayed queries, or a matrix of vectors.

Comment: There are two things here that are incomplete (and were incomplete in the OP): (1) the database connection (`mydb`) is instantiated each time but never closed; and (2) the result (`rs`) should be cleared with `dbClearResult`, or `dbSendQuery` should be replaced with `dbGetQuery` (and no need for `fetch`).